# In identity server 3 how to relate user to client

Tags: identityserver3

I am using Identity Server 3. I have couple applications ie. `Client` configured and have few users configured. How do i establish the relationship between User and a Client and also view all applications that the selected User has access to.

**Update 1**
I am sorry if question was confusing. On IdSvr3 home page, there is a link to revoke application permissions. I am guessing in order to revoke the permission you have to first establish the relationship between user and application. 
and i wanted to know how to establish that permission when i add new user?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to limit one or multiple users to a certain client. This is where you should think about implementing your own custom validation. Fortunately, the `IdentityServer` provides an extensibility point for this kind of requirement.

## ICustomRequestValidator

You should implement this interface to further validate users to see if they belong to certain clients and filter them out. You can look into the user details by looking at `ValidatedAuthorizeRequest.Subject`. This custom validator will start after validating optional parameters such as nonce, prompt, arc_values ( AuthenticationContextReference ), login_hint, and etc. The endpoint is [AuthorizeEndPointController](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Endpoints/Connect/AuthorizeEndpointController.cs) and the default implementation of the interface for the tailored job is [AuthorizeRequestValidator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Validation/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs) and its `RunValidationAsync`. You should take a look at the controller and the class.

**Implementation tip**

By the time the custom request validation begins, a `Client` reference will be presented in `ValidatedAuthorizeRequest`. So all you need to do would be matching the `client id` or some other identifiers you think you need to verify the client. Probably, you might want to add a `Claim` key-value pair to your client which you want to allow a few users.

Maybe something like this.

```
new InMemoryUser{Subject = "870805", Username = "damon", Password = "damon",
    Claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, "Damon Jeong"),
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "dmjeong@email.com"),
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean)                                  
    }
}
```

Assume you have above user, then add the subject id to the claim of a client like below.

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "WPF WebView Client Sample",
    ClientId = "wpf.webview.client",
    Flow = Flows.Implicit,

    .
    .
    .

    // Add claim for limiting this client to certain users.
    // Since a claim only accepts type and value as string,
    // You can add a list of subject id by comma separated values
    // eg ( new Claim("BelongsToThisUser", "870805, 870806, 870807") )
    Claims = new List<Claim>
    {
         new Claim("BelongsToThisUser", "870805")
    }
},
```

And then just implement the `ICustomRequestValidator` and try to match the `Claim` value with the given user in its `ValidateAuthorizeRequestAsync`.

```
public class UserRequestLimitor : ICustomRequestValidator
{
    public Task<AuthorizeRequestValidationResult> ValidateAuthorizeRequestAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request) 
    {
        var clientClaim = request.Client.claims.Where(x => x.Type == "BelongsToThisUser").FirstOrDefault();

        // Check is this client has "BelongsToThisUser" claim.
        if(clientClaim != null)
        {
             var subClaim = request.Subject.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "sub").FirstOrDefault() ?? new Claim(string.Empty, string.Empty);
             if(clientClaim.Value == userClaim.Value) 
             {
                 return Task.FromResult<AuthorizeRequestValidationResult>(new AuthorizeRequestValidationResult
                {
                    IsError = false
                });
             }
             else
             {
                 return Task.FromResult<AuthorizeRequestValidationResult>(new AuthorizeRequestValidationResult
                {
                    ErrorDescription = "This client doesn't have an authorization to request a token for this user.",
                    IsError = true
                });
             }
        }
        // This client has no access controls over users.
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthorizeRequestValidationResult>(new AuthorizeRequestValidationResult
            {
                IsError = false
            });
        }
    }

    public Task<TokenRequestValidationResult> ValidateTokenRequestAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request) 
    {
         // your implementation
    }
}
```

**Time to DI**

You need to inject your own dependency when you configure up your `IdentityServer`. The authorization server uses `IdentityServerServiceFactory` for registering dependencies.

```
var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
factory.Register(new Registration<ICustomRequestValidator>(resolver => new UserRequestLimitor()));
```

Then `Autofac`; the `IoC` container in *IdentityServer* will do the rest of the DI jobs for you.

Comment: Instead of adding User Into client's claim, can it be other way. Can we add Client into User's claim. And Client Application can just check existence of the claim in logged in user's claims list

Comment: @LP13 It really depends on what you want to do. If you want to add the key/value pair to a `User`, you're going to have to implement `IUserService`. You just don't get the newly added `Claim` property in the request context. There will be only `sub`, `name`, `amr`, `idp`, `auth_time` claims in your `Subject`. There should be a better way to do this after all. This is just an implementation tip.